# Yum update errors

Tags: centos, yum

I try to run yum update but I have three errors. I try to run the commands suggested but change nothing.
How I can solve this errors?

```
--> Processing Dependency: libzip.so.4 for package: php-pecl-zip-1.13.2-1.el6.remi.5.6.i686
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Error: Package: php-gd-5.6.20-1.el6.remi.i686 (remi-php56)
Requires: gd-last(x86-32) >= 2.1.1

Error: Package: php-gd-5.6.20-1.el6.remi.i686 (remi-php56)
Requires: libgd.so.3

Error: Package: php-pecl-zip-1.13.2-1.el6.remi.5.6.i686 (remi-php56)
Requires: libzip.so.4
```

Comment: What repositories to have you have enabled?

Comment: I updated the question with two previous lines of code

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28120410/centos-cant-install-php-gd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve using:

```
yum install php-gd --enablerepo=remi,remi-php55
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't even say what operating system you're running, one of the more likely issues is that you are missing 'extra packages for enterprise linux' or EPEL repository. you can confirm what repositories you are tracking using the repolist command

```
yum repolist
```

if you are using RHEL then you should register you server with them and seek support from Red Hat as you entitled to with you license, or you can install them from the links below.

if you are running RHEL/CentOS you can install the EPEL repo  using rpm as noted in the examples below, but the preferred approach is to install the rpm file with 'yum install epel-release-7-7.noarch.rpm'

## RHEL/CentOS 7 64-Bit

```
# wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/e/epel-release-7-5.noarch.rpm
# rpm -ivh epel-release-7-5.noarch.rpm
RHEL/CentOS 6 32-64 Bit
```

## RHEL/CentOS 6 32-Bit

```
# wget http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
# rpm -ivh epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
```

## RHEL/CentOS 6 64-Bit

```
# wget http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
# rpm -ivh epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
```

### RHEL/CentOS 5 32-64 Bit

```
# wget http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
# rpm -ivh epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
```

## RHEL/CentOS 5 64-Bit

```
# wget http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/x86_64/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
# rpm -ivh epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
```

### RHEL/CentOS 4 32-64 Bit

```
# wget http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/4/i386/epel-release-4-10.noarch.rpm
# rpm -ivh epel-release-4-10.noarch.rpm
```

## RHEL/CentOS 4 64-Bit

```
# wget http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/4/x86_64/epel-release-4-10.noarch.rpm
# rpm -ivh epel-release-4-10.noarch.rpm
```

Answer (score 1):

libzip-last and gd-last are in **remi-safe** repository which is enabled by default once you have install the **remi-release** (auto-configuration) package.

Remember to check the [Configuration Wizard](http://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/) instruction.